# using long string(over 4000) in oracle query

Tags: oracle, plsql, varchar2

I know that in sql varchar2 can only be around 4000.

I know that in oracle PL varchcar2 can be around 32000.

I have a varchar2 variable defined that is over 4000 characters long and I want to use it in a query. I don't want to insert the value into a table. The value is a dilimited string that I am parsing and inserting into a table with this query. This query works when the variable is less than 4000 characters long. Is there a way to make it work with up to 32000 characters?

```
create global temporary table t(single_element varchar(500),element_no number);
declare
--declared as 32767 but this string contains less than 4000 characters. 
--This will work. If you expand the string to 32000 characters it will not work.
myvar varchar2(32767) := 'tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4^~tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4';
begin
delete from t;
insert into t
SELECT SUBSTR(str, start_pos, (next_pos-start_pos)) AS single_element, element_no
FROM  (
        SELECT 
              ilv.str, 
              nt.column_value AS element_no, 
              INSTR(ilv.str, '^~', DECODE(nt.column_value, 1, 0, 1), DECODE(nt.column_value, 1, 1, nt.column_value-1)) + 2 AS start_pos,
              INSTR(ilv.str, '^~', 1, DECODE(nt.column_value, 1, 1, nt.column_value)) AS next_pos
        FROM   (
                select '~' || myvar || '^~' as str, 
                (Length(myvar) - length(replace(myvar,'^~','')))/2 + 2 as no_of_elements 
                from dual) ilv,

              TABLE(
                    CAST(
                       MULTISET(
                          SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY ROWNUM < ilv.no_of_elements
                          ) AS number_ntt )) nt
         );
end;
```

The error I get when expanding "myvar" to 32000 characters is

```
can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column
```

Is there a way I can get around this size restraint because i'm not actually inserting this value into a table, i'm just using it in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to define the variable as a VARCHAR2?  Could you define it as a CLOB instead?

If I change the declaration of `MYVAR` from a `VARCHAR2(32767)` to a `CLOB` and define the `NUMBER_NTT` type, your code runs for me

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

SP2-0161: line 2 truncated.
  1  declare
  2  myvar clob := 'tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testms
  <<snip>>
~tcd3~#testmsg3^~tcd4~#testmsg4';
  4  begin
  5  delete from t;
  6  insert into t
  7  SELECT SUBSTR(str, start_pos, (next_pos-start_pos)) AS single_element, elem
ent_no
  8  FROM  (
  9          SELECT
 10                ilv.str,
 11                nt.column_value AS element_no,
 12                INSTR(ilv.str, '^~', DECODE(nt.column_value, 1, 0, 1), DECODE
(nt.column_value, 1, 1, nt.column_value-1)) + 2 AS start_pos,
 13                INSTR(ilv.str, '^~', 1, DECODE(nt.column_value, 1, 1, nt.colu
mn_value)) AS next_pos
 14          FROM   (
 15                  select '~' || myvar || '^~' as str,
 16                  (Length(myvar) - length(replace(myvar,'^~','')))/2 + 2 as n
o_of_elements
 17                  from dual) ilv,
 18                TABLE(
 19                      CAST(
 20                         MULTISET(
 21                            SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY ROWNUM < ilv.n
o_of_elements
 22                            ) AS number_ntt )) nt
 23           );
 24* end;
 25  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select count(*) from t;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       172
```

That being said, that's not how I'd parse a delimited string, particularly in PL/SQL.  But it does the job.

Comment: I was trying to come up with a more efficient way to parse the string than looping. This does seem to be faster than looping through the delimited string and inserting each row individually. Did you have another idea on how to parse the string?

Comment: p.s. - i'm bias against non set-based operations... dbms operate in a set-based way by nature, I'm yet to see an example where there is a natural advantage to using loops over a set based solution.

Answer (score 1):

OK, well this skirts close to the edges of your implementation bias, although remember that forall IS a bulk-binding operation, not a real loop, but have you looked at the dbms_utility.comma_to_table function?

It is an optimized internal oracle parsing function, although with some limitations as you can read about here: http://www.techiegyan.com/2009/02/17/oracle-breaking-comma-separated-string-using-dbms_utilitycomma_to_table/

You would need to replace() to make it comma-delimited, and also double-quotes-enclose if you have parsed fields that starts with numbers, special characters, contains commas, etc

But if your data will allow - it sure makes your code look cleaner (and will likely work much faster too)

```
declare
   myvar      varchar2(32000) := 'tcd1~#testmsg1^~tcd2~#testmsg2^~tcd3~#testmsg3';
   mycnt      binary_integer;
   myresults  sys.dbms_utility.lname_array;
begin
   sys.dbms_utility.comma_to_table('"'||replace(myvar,'^~','","')||'"', mycnt, myresults );
   delete from t;
   forall ix in myresults.first..myresults.last 
      insert into tvalues (myresults(ix));
   commit;
end;
```

Comment: thought of this, however if they are using two special characters as delimiters, I would guess that it is because they can't guarantee that the data does not contain commas...